# Is there an offence when you kill to prevent a murder?

Tags: criminal-law, united-kingdom, is-x-legal, homicide

Suppose Person A shoots and kills Person B, who was about to shoot to kill Person C, and Person C makes a statement to police to say that if Person A hadn’t intervened, there was no doubt they would have died (i.e. Person B actually pulled the trigger, and only missed due to a bullet to the head).

In the United Kingdom, what crime could Person A be charged with? What might be the minimum sentence, if they can be found guilty?

Comment: The question's purely about the killing, right? I assume many other laws would be broken in your scenario.

Comment: @bobsburner Hi, yes, purely about the killing. The situation is really complicated in terms of the law and how many he has broken before getting to the killing.  But the book's being published soon, so it's too late to change it now. He does go to jail but not for murder as it is deemed self-defence, but as your suspicions rightly suggest, he's broken so many other laws he ends up in jail anyway despite getting away with murder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### [Murder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murder)

Which is the unlawful taking of a life with intent to do so.

However, the doctrine of [self-defence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-defence_in_English_law) can make killing lawful:

> A person may use such force as is reasonable in the circumstances in the prevention of crime, or in effecting or assisting in the lawful arrest of offenders or suspected offenders or of persons unlawfully at large.

if the prosecutor is of the opinion that the force used "is reasonable in the circumstances" they may not lay charges. If they do lay charges the judge may decide that there is no case to answer before going to trial if self-defence applies. If there is a trial this will probably be the strategy the defence employs and they may or may not be successful.

If convicted the penalty is life imprisonment.

Also, there is no UK law: there is the law of England and Wales, the law of Scotland and the law of Northern Ireland.

Comment: Dale, thank you so much, I really appreciate your time. That link and the Palmer v The Queen quote is super helpful too. I'm on a deadline and so grateful for your quick response.

Comment: Dale, can I ask one more thing... roughly how long would it take, from arrest to acquittal, if the prosecutor did decide that reasonable force had been used and no charges should be laid? I'm aware this is a 'how long is a piece of string' question, but it doesn't need to be accurate, just believable. Thx!

Comment: In the circumstances described, the person would probably never be arrested.

Comment: Oh, that's great!  That *really* helps my timeline. A drawn out legal process would have made things really difficult. THANK YOU!!!!

Comment: @GGx Only if it is obvious that this is really what happened. When there are no other witnesses, it might be reasonable for the police or even the prosecution to suspect that A and C might have conspired to murder B and get away with it by claiming it was a self-defense situation.

Comment: @Philipp Thanks! There's another witness and she's a police officer.

Comment: @GGx Who is "she"? A, B or C? "Killing a police officer because she was threatening someone with her firearm" will likely **not** be considered self-defense because police officers are usually allowed to do that.

Comment: If the police officer is the witness, then her interpretation of the situation might be relevant. When the officer says that she had the situation under control and the use of deadly force by A wasn't necessary, then a lengthy process might not be so unlikely anymore.

Comment: @Philipp you're a star for making sure I get this right, you have no idea how much I appreciate it. I have half a dozen other questions if you're interested in the legalities of this fictional case!?  I'd give you credit if the book gets published too!  But the police officer doesn't have the situation under control. Prior to the shooting, Person B has already drugged the police officer with scopolamine, coerced her into cutting her own wrists, and she's bleeding out in the bathtub upstairs. So, when person A shoots person B, he actually saves two lives. The police officer and Person C.